# No Code output in sublime text 3, C++. I have tried the solution in previous posts

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When there is no error in my code, I get this message in sublime
as you can see just build time but no output
I have added the mingW/bin folder to my path variable.
Here is my build system-

```
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
]
}
```

Do I need to make any changes to this? If yes, please let me know.
ALso when I press ctrl+b does it compile the entire .cpp file or does it only compile the current line?
Please help a fellow computer enthusiast out, I have looked it up on stack overflow, sublime forum but I cannot seem to find any answer out there.

Comment: You don't need your own build for this; Sublime comes with a build that's exactly this that will work for you. Your problem is that when you were asked to choose which build to use, you didn't pick the one that says `Run`, so all your'e doing is compiling your program. Use `Tools > Build WIth...` and then select the `Run` variant when prompted.

Comment: @OdatNurd- Are you talking about the ```C++ single``` file build system? I have tried to build using it's ```Run``` variant as well. However, it still shows the build time only. The output is still not visible.  Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: What's your code look like?

Comment: Hi, it was indeed my code that was causing this problem. It was one particular line that was causing this error. I was using an unordered_map in C++. When I was using the map.begin() function as following
```if(bmap.find(element)!=bmap.end()|| bmap.find(element)!=bmap.begin())```

Comment: Hey  @SuhritRao did you got the solution? I'm also facing same issue :(

Comment: Hi @SHIVAMDUBEY. Try all previous posts on stack exchange. If they still didn't work, there must be an issue in your code then, it is possible that it's not giving any output. In my case it happened because my output was inside an if condition which never satisfied.